# Can't define a variable in html

Tags: javascript, html

Guys I can't define variable in html .. Here is my code below:-

```
sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div id='Button +"i"' class=\"" + getClass(c.getIndex()) + "\">");
```

Here I can't define "i" to be a variable .. Any help please ??

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is `sb`? please provide a [mcve] of your problem

Comment: my problem is in the "i" variable

Comment: you are missing a `+` before **and** after `i`

Comment: sb.appendHtmlConstant('<div id="Button '+i+'" class=\"" + getClass(c.getIndex()) + "\">");

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `+` before and after it.

```
sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div id='Button "+i+"' class=\"" + getClass(c.getIndex()) + "\">");
```

Adding variable to strings in java works like this:

```
String variable = "the variable string";
```

And we want to add it so that we get:

```
"We want to add _the variable string_ to here"
```

So we'll use:

```
String result = "We want to add _"+ variable +"_ to here";
                                 ^/*This and ^this are important*/
```

Comment: @luk2302 whoops. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i should be out of the main quotes I think, as below:

```
sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div id='Button" + i + "' class=\"" + getClass(c.getIndex()) + "\">");
```